# How can I translate this legacy SQL to standard SQL in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to translate this to BigQuery. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
IF DATEDIFF('day',DATEADD('day',7,snapshot_date),TODAY(),'monday')>=1
THEN 1
END
```

This is the error I'm getting.

> The Google BigQuery Standard SQL database encountered an error while
> running this query. Query execution failed: - Syntax error: Expected
> "(" but got identifier "DATEDIFF" at [2:25]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)):

```
IF(DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(snapshot_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY), CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) >= 1, 1, NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
case when DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(snapshot_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY), CURRENT_DATE(), WEEK(MONDAY)) >= 1 then 1  end
```